# How to select multiple rows where a word is distinct by its letter?

Tags: mysql

The title may be confusing, but so is the solution I am trying to SELECT from a table of 173k words a distinct word list by letter.

I already tried selecting distinct letters, running on a mariadb 10.1.37

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(word, 1)
```

For example a SELECT shouldnt contain more than 1 word beginning with an "A".

Example Table (Because it's hard to understand)

```
╔═══════════╦═════════╗
║    Word   ║  Result ║
╠═══════════╣   ----  ║
║  Charlie  ║   Ava   ║
╠═══════════╣  Bianca ║
║   Caddie  ║ Charlie ║
╠═══════════╣         ║
║ Brooklynn ║         ║
╠═══════════╣         ║
║    Ava    ║         ║
╠═══════════╣         ║
║ Alexander ║         ║
╠═══════════╣         ║
║   Bianca  ║         ║
╚═══════════╩═════════╝
```

Comment: why  ..  charlie ??

Comment: Why not Alexander instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using a `GROUP BY` on the first character:

```
SELECT MIN(word) FROM table_name GROUP BY LEFT(word, 1)
```

You can use `MIN` or `MAX` to get the first or last word on every group.

> [**demo un dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5c9b10d227da1307c3d09b9118e83d4)